# How to check the self-hosted Azure Devops agent configuration details on Linux

Tags: azure-devops

We have many Azure Devops Projects and agents pools. One of the Linux machine having self-hosted agent is not working and I need to collect details about this installed agent.

Is there direct way to check the below details for agent:

- Agent name
- Agent Pool name or Deployment Group name
- Azure DevOps organization

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#systemd-service-file) speaks very little about it only indicating a systemd service file like `/etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.{tfs-name}.{agent-name}.service`.

Is there more explicit command(s) to determine these details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file `myagent/.agent` with these details:

```json
{
"acceptTeeEula": true,
"agentId": 13,
"agentName": "centos",
"poolId": 13,
"poolName": "ubuntu-linux-local-hyperv",
"serverUrl":"https://dev.azure.com/org_name/",
"workFolder": "_work"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, there is  `.agent` (no name before) file in agent folder that can be opened with txt. Try finding the similar  file.

Content:

```
{
  "agentId": 9,
  "agentName": "XX",
  "poolId": 1,
  "poolName": "Default",
  "serverUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/XXX/",
  "workFolder": "_work"
}
```

Comment: `How to check the self-hosted Azure Devops agent configuration details on Linux` - OP is, as stated, checking Linux, not Windows. Please make sure that answers are relevant to the question and provides enough detail for the OP to find what they need